# VBS in HTA to pull sys info

Tags: vbscript, hta

How do i pull those fields into a text box for each in an HTA.  i just need to pull this info into a text box to display on my HTA along with the rest of the info

```
Sub getinfo
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly       = &h20

On Error Resume Next
If WScript.Arguments.UnNamed.Count = 1 Then
strComputer = WScript.Arguments.UnNamed(0)
Else
    strComputer = "."
End If

Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2" )
Set colInstances = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly )

For Each objInstance In colInstances
 WScript.Echo "Domain                      : " & objInstance.Domain
 WScript.Echo "Manufacturer                : " & objInstance.Manufacturer
 WScript.Echo "Model                       : " & objInstance.Model
 WScript.Echo "UserName                    : " & objInstance.UserName

    Next

   end sub
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. I'm afraid your question is too broad to answer here. I don't see a `HTA`-like code to see how your _text box_ is defined. Please read and follow [ask], especially _include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem_. [A hint for your question](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx): `innerText` or `innerHTML` property could be useful

Comment: how do i use wscript.echo to write to an html box. this is all new to me so please bear with me sorry

Comment: You could learn [here](http://www.akaplan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Scriptomatic_hta.txt). Look for `"code"` and for `code.InnerHTML` settings. Use `wscript.echo` in the same manner like there.

Answer (score 1):

Append to the textarea's value. **Minimal** sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <hta:application id = "id"></hta>
  <script language = "VBScript" type = "text/vbscript">
'<![CDATA[

Option Explicit

Sub Window_OnLoad()
  Dim taSysInfo : Set taSysInfo = document.GetElementById("taSysInfo")
  Dim i
  For i = 1 to 5
      taSysInfo.value = taSysInfo.value & "line " & i & vbCrLf
  Next
End Sub

']]>
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
   <textarea cols="80" id="taSysInfo" rows="20"></textarea>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try for this HTA :

```
<HTA:APPLICATION
  BORDERSTYLE = ""
  CAPTION="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU = "yes"
  INNERBORDER = "no"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON = "no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON = "no"
  NAVIGABLE = "Yes"
  SCROLL = "No"
  SCROLLFLAT = "Yes"
  SELECTION="Yes"
  SYSMENU="yes"
  SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  VERSION = "1.0"
  BORDER="thin"
  >
 <script language="VBScript"> 
 Dim intRamAmt, strCompName, strUserName, strModel
 Dim strCPUSpeed, strManufacturer, strAssetTag
 Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 strComputer = "." 

 Sub Popup(Msg,Wait,Title)
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set ws  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
 Dim tempName : tempName = "Popup.vbs"
  Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(tempFolder&"\"&tempName, True)
  objOutputFile.Writeline "Set WshShell = CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")"
  objOutputFile.WriteLine "BtnCode = WshShell.Popup("&qq(Msg)&","&qq(wait)&","&qq(Title)&",48)"
  objOutputFile.Close
  ws.Run tempFolder&"\"&tempName
End Sub

Function qq(strIn) 
    qq = Chr(34) & strIn & Chr(34)
End Function

 Sub Window_Onload
  window.resizeTo 1,1
  Call Popup("Please be patient until loading all informations and the form will be resized !",30,"Please be patient until loading all informations and the form will be resized !")
 '##### Get Screen Resolution
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
      "SELECT * FROM Win32_DisplayConfiguration",,48) 
  For Each objItem in colItems 
     intHorizontal = objItem.PelsWidth
     intVertical = objItem.PelsHeight
  Next
 '###### Get UserName, ComputerName, ComputerModel, & RAM
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
       "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem",,48) 
  For Each objItem In colItems
   strCompName = objItem.Name
   strUserName = objItem.UserName
   strModel = objItem.Model
   intRAMamt = Int(objItem.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1048576) & "MB"
  Next
 '####### Get CPU Information
  Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
       "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor",,48)
  For Each ObjItem In ColItems
   strCPUSpeed = objItem.CurrentClockSpeed & "MHz"
  Next
 '####### Get Manufacturer & Serial Number
  Set objSysCol = objWMIService.ExecQuery ( _
    "Select * from Win32_BIOS",,48)
  For Each objSys In ObjSysCol
   strManufacturer = Objsys.Manufacturer
   strAssetTag = ObjSys.SerialNumber
  Next
 '####### Get SP Level & OS
  Set objSysCol = objWMIService.ExecQuery ( _
    "Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
  For each m In ObjSysCol
   strOS = m.caption
   strPatchLevelMajor = m.ServicePackMajorVersion
   strPatchLevelMinor = m.ServicePackMinorVersion
  Next
  intSPLevel = strPatchLevelMajor & "." & strPatchLevelMinor
  strOS = strOS & " SP " & intSPLevel
 '####### Get list of USB devices
  Set colDevices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
      ("Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice")
  For Each objDevice in colDevices
      strDeviceName = objDevice.Dependent
      strQuotes = Chr(34)
      strDeviceName = Replace(strDeviceName, strQuotes, "")
      arrDeviceNames = Split(strDeviceName, "=")
      strDeviceName = arrDeviceNames(1)
     Set colUSBDevices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
         ("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '" & strDeviceName & "'")
      For Each objUSBDevice in colUSBDevices
       Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
    objOption.Text = objUSBDevice.Name
    objOption.Value = objUSBDevice.Name
    USBDevices.Add(objOption)
      Next    
  Next
 '###### Get last configured NIC w/ IP address
  Set IPConfigSet = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
   ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" _
  & " where IPEnabled=TRUE")
  For Each IPConfig in IPConfigSet
   If Not IsNull(IPConfig.IPAddress) Then 
    For i=LBound(IPConfig.IPAddress) to UBound(IPConfig.IPAddress)
     strMacAddr = IpConfig.MACaddress(i)
     strIPAddr = IpConfig.IPAddress(i)
     strNetworkCard = Mid(Ipconfig.Caption(i),12,Len(Ipconfig.Caption(i))-11)
    Next
    If i > 1 Then strIPAddr = strIPaddr & " ( > than 1 IP - check card)"
   End If
   Exit For
  Next 
 '###### Get complete list of Network Cards
 Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
     "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter",,48) 
  For Each objItem in colItems 
  Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
  objOption.Text = Mid(ObjItem.Caption,12, Len(ObjItem.Caption)-11)
  objOption.Value = Mid(ObjItem.Caption,12, Len(ObjItem.Caption)-11)
  NetDevices.Add(objOption)
 Next
 '###### Get list of Drives
 Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
     "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk",,48) 
 For Each objItem in colItems 
  If objItem.Name <> "A:" Then
  Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
  objOption.Text = objItem.Name & "-Total:" & int(objItem.Size / 107526550)*.1 & "GB" & "-Free Space:" & int(objItem.FreeSpace / 107526550)*.1 & "GB"
  DiskDevices.Add(objOption)
  End IF
 Next
  frmCompName.InnerHTML = strCompName
  frmstrUserName.InnerHTML = strUserName
  frmstrManufacturer.InnerHTML = strManufacturer
  frmstrModel.InnerHTML = strModel
  frmstrAssetTag.InnerHTML = strAssetTag
  frmstrCPUSpeed.InnerHTML = strCPUSpeed
  frmintRAMamt.InnerHTML = intRAMamt
  frmstrOS.InnerHTML = strOS
  frmstrMacAddr.InnerHTML = strMacAddr
  frmstrIPAddr.InnerHTML = strIPAddr
  frmstrNetworkCard.InnerHTML = strNetworkCard

  window.resizeTo 640,300
  intLeft = (intHorizontal - 640) / 2
  intTop = (intVertical - 300) / 2
  window.moveTo intLeft, intTop
 End Sub
 </script>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Computer Information</title>
 <style type="text/css">
  @import "all.css"; /* just some basic formatting, no layout stuff */
   body {
   background-color:black;
   margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
   }
  table {
   border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
   padding:0px 0px 5px 5px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   font-size: 75%;
   }
  .tblborderline {
   border-bottom: 2px solid white;
   border-top-width: 5px;
   }
  th {
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
   text-align: right;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   font-weight: normal;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   }
  td {
   background-color: black;
   color: yellow;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   font-weight: bold;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>Computer Name:</th>
   <td><span id=frmCompName></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>User Name:</th>
      <td><span id=frmstrUserName></span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <th class="tblborderline">OS:</th>
      <td class="tblborderline"><span id=frmstrOS></span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
   <th>Manufacturer:</th>
      <td><span id=frmstrManufacturer></span></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
   <th>Model:</th>
      <td><span id=frmstrModel></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="tblborderline">Asset Tag:</th>
      <td class="tblborderline"><span id=frmstrAssetTag></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>CPU Speed:</th>
     <td><span id=frmstrCPUSpeed></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>Memory:</th>
     <td><span id=frmintRAMamt></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>NIC:</th>
     <td><span id=frmstrNetworkCard></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>IP:</th>
     <td><span id=frmstrIPAddr></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
     <th class="tblborderline">MAC:</th>
     <td class="tblborderline"><span id=frmstrMacAddr></span></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
     <th>DISK Devices:</h>
     <td><select name="DiskDevices"></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>NET Devices:</th>
     <td><select name="NetDevices"></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th>USB Devices:</th>
     <td><select name="USBDevices"></select></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i was able to work out a resolution but now i have a new problem! i'll post a new question! thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I translated your `WScript.Echo` lines to `textarea.write` lines by:

1. Create a TEXTAREA in HTML
2. Declare JavaScript `write()` function for that TEXTAREA
3. Invoke the `write()` function in VBScript
4. By declaring everything at the end of the BODY element, we know most of the DOM is ready and can be used by the script (saves us writing `Window_OnLoad` handler)

It's, effectively, you're code, with minimal HTA embellishments applied:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9" />
</head>
<body>
<textarea cols="80" id="taSysInfo" rows="20">
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
taSysInfo.write = function(txt) { taSysInfo.value += txt + "\r\n"; }
</script>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly       = &h20
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2" )
Set colInstances = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly )
For Each objInstance In colInstances
    taSysInfo.write "Domain                      : " & objInstance.Domain
    taSysInfo.write "Manufacturer                : " & objInstance.Manufacturer
    taSysInfo.write "Model                       : " & objInstance.Model
    taSysInfo.write "UserName                    : " & objInstance.UserName
Next
</script>
</body>
</html>
```