# Is it possible to get direct output from WMIC in HTA's IE11 WSShell?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, hta, ws

I know this is a really outdated technology, however Id still like to gather some information about the system the HTA is running on (CPU Model etc) and display it right in the same window. The problem comes with IE11, where the GetObject function is no longer a thing and so I have to find some other ways, I tried a load of different things but either I wasnt able to retrieve the output or it simply wouldnt work/wouldnt contain information I want. So, currently Im without any code as nothing even remotely worked, so is there currently any way to retrieve information like CPU Model, GPU Model, RAM etc with IE11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBS in HTA to pull sys info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733994/vbs-in-hta-to-pull-sys-info)

Answer (score 0):

The code below retrieves the data you requested and runs as an HTA. It's a variation of the code posted here:
[VBS in HTA to pull sys info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733994/vbs-in-hta-to-pull-sys-info)
It uses VBScript so, it's set to run in IE9 mode, but that runs fine on Windows 10 and Windows 11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="ta1" cols="80" rows="20">
</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
ta1.write = function(txt) {ta1.value += txt + "\r\n";}
</script>
<script type="text/vbscript">
window.resizeTo 700,400
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
Set colProcessors = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Processor")
For Each oItem in colProcessors
    ta1.write "Name                : " & oItem.Name
    ta1.write "Description         : " & oItem.Description
    ta1.write "Processor ID        : " & oItem.ProcessorID
    ta1.write "Address Width       : " & oItem.AddressWidth
    ta1.write "Data Width          : " & oItem.DataWidth
    ta1.write "Family              : " & oItem.Family
    ta1.write "Maximum Clock Speed : " & oItem.MaxClockSpeed
Next
Set oItems = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory")
For Each oItem in oItems
    ta1.write "Total Memory        : " & oItem.Capacity
Next
Set oItems = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_VideoController")
For Each oItem in oItems
    ta1.write "Display Adapter     : " & oItem.Description
    ta1.write "Driver Version      : " & oItem.DriverVersion
    ta1.write "Adapter RAM         : " & Abs(oItem.AdapterRAM)
Next
</script>
</body>
</html>
```