# Reading REG_QWORD with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I think the question speaks for itself. I have trouble getting some values out of the registry, and I was hoping someone around here might help me.

I'm stuck at IE9, as it is the only one which has some reasonable CSS capabilities, and does support `GetObject()`.

So right now, lets say I'm trying to retrieve the memory size of a GPU at `"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000\HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"` (as far as I know, this should be a universal path & key).

This is where the problem begins. Either I get no output, or some error saying something is different, or what (my system is running in a different language so I cant offer the right translation).

After some research, I seem to have found the issue - the value I'm trying to read is `REG_QWORD`, and unfortunately I was only able to find very little covering this topic, and most of the solutions did not work for me.

So right now, I am with this code, which, unsurprisingly, also does not work (the code I had since like the beginning):

```
for Each oItem in colGPUs
    memory = oItem.AdapterRAM / 1048576
    If memory < 0 Then
        If InStr(oItem.Name, "NVIDIA") Then
            Set wssx = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            msgbox CStr(wssx.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000" + GPUID + "\HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize"))
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: We can help, but you need to tell us what you have tried what so far, what code you have, and where you are stuck. You can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @Mokubai done. I didnt even think about the fact you actually need the code and more backstory etc

Comment: The `WScript.Shell` object simply does not support `REG_QWORD`, for either reading or writing. You might try using WMI instead, specifically the [`StdRegProv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/regprov/stdregprov) class and its [`GetQWORDValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/regprov/getqwordvalue-method-in-class-stdregprov) method. See [this example](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_registry_stdregprov.php)

Comment: The IE9/CSS reference implies an HTA. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807325/is-it-possible-to-get-direct-output-from-wmic-in-htas-ie11-wsshell

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly it seems like there is no direct way of retrieving the value - within HTA itself.

I was able to get the value, however I did it using Powershell, executed the command, set its output to a specific file and read it.

Anyways, here is the actual solution I came up with specifically for this issue

```
wshell.Run "powershell (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0000' 'HardwareInformation.qwMemorySize') | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\gpu_mem.txt", 0, true
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\gpu_mem.txt", 1, False, -1)
gpu_mem = CStr(f.ReadAll)
```

With this method Im directly obtaining the integer and passing it to the VBS